# Does a singular value decomposition always exist for complex matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

I know for real matrix A, SVD always exists, but I am wondering for any complex matrix, will SVD still exist for any scenarios? Thanks.

Comment: And how to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Complex matrices have well-defined Moore-Penrose pseudoinverses (apparently according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse if so then I learned that today myself too). Assuming that's the case, then the proof of existence of SVD using Moore-Penrose pseudoinverses that works for real matrices probably should also work for complex matrices -- have you tried it? In any case Wikipedia also claims that SVD's exist for complex matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition but I've never seen them myself, so I'm curious what the answer is too

Comment: Apparently you can prove existence combining the polar decomposition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition with the spectral theorem for normal matrices, cf. this section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition . Of course that kind of kicks the can down the road, namely why do polar decompositions exist -- I've never learned that myself but from everything I've read it seems that understanding polar decompositions would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

One way to see this is by thinking of SVD as $X = U^\ddagger V$ where:

- $X\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times P}$, where $N > P$, without loss of generality
- $U \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$ and $U^\ddagger U = I$
- $V \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times P}$ and $V^\ddagger V = \Lambda$ , where $\Lambda$ is $P \times P$ diagonal and *real* matrix

That is, given $x$ to we want to  solve for $u$ and $v$, where (in einstein notation) the following equations hold
$$
x_{i,j} = u_{i,k}.v_{k,j}
\\ u_{i,k}.u{j,k} = \delta_{i,j}
\\ v_{i,k}.v_{j,k} = \delta_{i,j} .\lambda_{i}, 
$$
where $\lambda_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$, and as always, $\delta_{i,j} = 1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

So now we have a system with $2\times(N^2 + NP)$ unknowns, subject to $2NP$ + $N^2$ + $P^2$ constraints  (the 2 factor since they are  complex values), and $P < N$ as assumed.

So because the number of unknowns is less than the number of *linear* constraints the problem is solvable.

Comment: Thanks so much, besides, for uniqueness, does the conclusion "if all singular values of a square matrix M are non-degenerate and non-zero, then its singular value decomposition is unique" also apply to the complex matrix?